# How to upload video file on parse in android?

Tags: android, parse-server

I am trying to upload video file on parse. For uploading the video I am using following code:

```
    File inputFile = new File(uri.toString());
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[(int)inputFile.length()];

        for (int readNum; (readNum=fis.read(buf)) != -1;){
            bos.write(buf,0,readNum);
        }
        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
    ParseFile file = new ParseFile("testVideo1.mp4", bytes);
    ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("chat1");
    parseObject.saveInBackground();
```

But `inputfile` the `File` object not converted to `FileInputStream`.

Comment: can you share the error message.

Comment: Hey bud, though this is not an answer, you might want to consiser [this](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/)

Comment: it doesnot give any error message.but the code not executes after the first line. code stuck on the line:     
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

Comment: @Skynet the same SDK works for Parse Server. Nothing about Parse.com was mentioned in the question

Comment: Cricket, sorry but I am not able to get what you mean?

Comment: How did you handle the fis.read IO Exception?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the this, helped me get started with uploading a video to parse, I figure out your issue, you just didn't put the parse file in your parseobject. basically you never sent the video

```
File inputFile = new File(uri.toString());
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[(int)inputFile.length()];

    for (int readNum; (readNum=fis.read(buf)) != -1;){
        bos.write(buf,0,readNum);
    }
    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
ParseFile file = new ParseFile("testVideo1.mp4", bytes);
ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("chat1");
//addition
parseObject.put("video",file);
//it should work with this
parseObject.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: Hello!! readNum =fis.read(buf) needs to handle an IO exception ... how did you do it if the read is inside the for loop?